# How can I append new data to existing xml with python

Tags: python, xml

Hello Here is my existing xml file

```
<domain type='kvm'>
      <name>mydomain</name>
      <features>
        <acpi/>
        <apic/>
        <pae/>
      </features>
      <devices>
        <disk type='block' device='disk'>
          <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
          <source dev='/dev/mydomain'/>
          <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
        </disk>
      </devices>
</domain>
```

I would like to append the another **"disk section"** in the above xml under **"devices"** section so my new xml will like this.

```
<domain type='kvm'>
      <name>mydomain</name>
      <features>
        <acpi/>
        <apic/>
        <pae/>
      </features>
      <devices>
        <disk type='block' device='disk'>
          <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
          <source dev='/dev/mydomain'/>
          <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
        </disk>
        <disk type='block' device='disk'>
          <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
          <source dev='/dev/mydomain2'/>
          <target dev='vdb' bus='virtio'/>
        </disk>
      </devices>
</domain>
```

Would you please help me how I can do with Python XML

Br.

Umar

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse and update XML.

Here is a code to do that.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_new_element():
    #create element and set attributes
    disk = ET.Element('disk')
    disk.attrib['type'] = 'block'
    disk.attrib['device'] = 'disk'

    #create sub-element and set attributes
    driver = ET.SubElement(disk, 'driver')
    driver.attrib['name'] = 'qemu'
    driver.attrib['type'] = 'raw'
    driver.attrib['cache'] = 'none'

    source = ET.SubElement(disk, 'source')
    source.attrib['dev'] = '/dev/mydomain2'

    target = ET.SubElement(disk, 'target')
    target.attrib['dev'] = 'vdb'
    target.attrib['bus'] = 'virtio'

    return disk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    xml_tree = ET.parse('data.xml')
    devices_element = xml_tree.find('devices')

    new_element = get_new_element()
    devices_element.append(new_element)

    new_xml_tree_string = ET.tostring(xml_tree.getroot())

    with open('updated_data.xml', "wb") as f:
        f.write(new_xml_tree_string)
```

For `pretty` XML follow: [Pretty-Printing XML](https://pymotw.com/2/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html)

Comment: Hello parshkr, thanks for your help, I have xml in a variable instead as a file, so what I need to use in alternative of ET.parse()?

Comment: You can use `ET.fromstring(your_xml_string)`. In that case I believe you won't need to do `xml_tree.getroot()`

Comment: @Tears No need to thank me, just UP VOTE and ACCEPT the answer. ;)